# How to write a full struct in a file?

Tags: c

In my program, I receive input from the keyboard. I put that input in a `struct` that contains two `char` fields and 1 `int` field. How can I write into the entire `struct` using only a function?

I **don't** want to write into each member of the `struct` individually.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Can you add some code to your question, so we can understand it better?

Comment: Just pass the pointer of structure to the instruction. You don't need to write the members.

Comment: I ll add later, now I can use only smartphone for internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how your `struct` is defined, whether or not you want your output to be human-readable, and whether or not the output file is meant to be read on a different architecture.

The `fwrite` solution that others have given will write the *binary representation* of the struct to the output file.  For example, given the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  struct foo {
    int x;
    char name1[10];
    char name2[10];
  } items[] = {{1,"one","ONE"}, {2,"two","TWO"}};

  FILE *output = fopen("binio.dat", "w");

  fwrite( items, sizeof items, 1, output );

  fclose( output );
  return 0;
}
```

if I display the contents of `binio.dat` to the console, I get the following:

```
john@marvin:~/Development/Prototypes/C/binio$ cat binio.dat
oneONEtwoTWOjohn@marvin:~/Development/Prototypes/C/binio$ 

john@marvin:~/Development/Prototypes/C/binio$ od -c binio.dat
0000000 001  \0  \0  \0   o   n   e  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0   O   N
0000020   E  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
0000040  \0  \0  \0  \0 002  \0  \0  \0   t   w   o  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
0000060  \0  \0   T   W   O  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
0000100  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
0000110
```

The integer values show up as garbage (not reproduced above) because they've been stored as the byte sequences 01, 00, 00, 00 and 02, 00, 00, 00 (x86 is little-endian), which are not printable characters.  Also note that all 10 characters of `name1` and all 20 characters of `name2` are written to the file, which may or may not be what you want.

The situation gets even more complicated if your struct contains pointers, because what gets stored to the file is the pointer value, not the thing being pointed to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  struct foo {
    int x;
    char *name1;
    char *name2;
  } items[] = {{1,"one","ONE"}, {2,"two","TWO"}};

  FILE *output = fopen("binio.dat", "w");

  fwrite( items, sizeof items, 1, output );

  fclose( output );
  return 0;
}
```

This time I get

```
john@marvin:~/Development/Prototypes/C/binio$ cat binio.dat
��������john@marvin:~/Development/Prototypes/C/binio$ 

john@marvin:~/Development/Prototypes/C/binio$ od -c binio.dat
0000000 001  \0  \0  \0 260 205 004  \b 264 205 004  \b 002  \0  \0  \0
0000020 270 205 004  \b 274 205 004  \b
0000030
```

Note that none of the strings appear in the file at all; if you read this file in with a different program, all it will see are (most likely) invalid addresses.

If you want your output to be human-readable *and* you want to be able to read those values in on a different architecture, you almost have to go with formatted output, meaning you have to write each member separately:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  struct foo {
    int x;
    char *name1;
    char *name2;
  } items[] = {{1,"one","ONE"}, {2,"two","TWO"}};

  FILE *output = fopen("binio.dat", "w");
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof items / sizeof items[0]; i++)
  {
    fprintf(output, "%d %s %s\n", items[i].x, items[i].name1, items[i].name2);
  }
  fclose( output );
  return 0;
}
```

```
john@marvin:~/Development/Prototypes/C/binio$ cat binio.dat
1 one ONE
2 two TWO
```

You can certainly wrap that operation in a function of your own, something like

```
int printFoo( FILE *output, const struct foo item )
{
  return fprintf( output, "%d %s %s\n", item.x, item.name1, item.name2);
}
```

but in the end, that's about as simple as it gets.

The `fwrite` solution works great if you're not concerned about readability and portability, but you still have to be careful if you have any pointer members within the struct.

Answer (score 4):

C doesn't have "instructions".

You should be able to use a single function call, such as:

```
fwrite(&mystructure, sizeof mystructure, 1, myfile);
```

But this isn't without drawbacks:

1. This makes the file-format depend on your current CPU and compiler, which is often a bad idea; it will make it very hard to preserve interoperability.
2. The write might partially succeed; you need to wrap it in a loop for that case.